# My Lenovo ThinkPad T450 Backlit keyboard stopped working but lights up during Restart Boot up only

Tags: laptop, keyboard, thinkpad

I had an issue with my ThinkPad where it was failing to wake from sleep, i tried everything from resetting it with the hole on the back to disconnecting the CMOS and internal battery, finally, i took it to the repair guy who fixed it in seconds, but the shortcut of FN + SPACEBAR DOESNT turn on my keyboard light, i have tried the following below with no success

Using Lenovo Vantage: Doesn't show the Backlight settings

Driver Update: Can't find any driver that addresses keyboard issue, updated Bios and Chipset just in case

The power Drain method did not work

How can i fix this issue because it lights up during Bootup but the shortcut ain't working

Comment: Just an idea: Some laptops have in BIOS an option to disable the FN function.

Comment: Boot with a bootable USB Key (Windows or Linux) and see if the keyboard lights up that way. My Lenovo keyboards light up this way.